# flutter: how colorScheme property of ThemeData works?

Tags: flutter, dart

So for color scheme to Material app

```
              colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(

                          primary: Color(0xff075e54),
                          secondary: Color(0xffeacb2d),
                   ),
```

My question is `ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith()` works and gives 2 colors
primary and secondary.but if I go like `ColorScheme().copyWith()`
it doesn't work ? why? what is difference between `ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith()`
and `ColorScheme().copyWith()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `ThemeData` is a `Flutter` class, which come with default values for all its property when you get this:

```
 ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith()
```

you're trying to get the `colorSheme` property on that built-in `ThemeData` in the flutter framework, then override its values with the `copyWith()` method.
basically, it is like you get an already property that exists then update it.

now, when you use:

```
ColorScheme()
```

you're calling the constructor of the `ColorSheme` class which as you see:

```
const ColorScheme({
required this.brightness,
required this.primary,
required this.onPrimary,
Color? primaryContainer,
Color? onPrimaryContainer,
required this.secondary,
required this.onSecondary,
Color? secondaryContainer,
Color? onSecondaryContainer,
/*...*/
```

some properties are required, so in order to call a full new `ColorSheme` constructor, you need to provide values for every `required` property inside it, after that you can say.

```
ColorScheme(/* after all properties are set*/).copyWith()
```

so you can copy it and override its values.

the `ColorScheme` have `factory` constructors which let you get default values based on the [Material Design scheme colors](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation) like `ColorScheme.light()`, `ColorScheme.dark()`...
which you can use directly, or override its values like this:

```
ColorScheme.light().copyWith()
```